# SQL Server stored procedure using INNER JOIN

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_STORED_PROCEDURE]
AS
BEGIN  
  SELECT 
     CUSTOMER_NAME,
     CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_ID
  FROM CUSTOMER
  INNER JOIN PRODUCT ON PRODUCT_ID = CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_ID
END
```

I select data from product table. However, if `CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_ID` is `null`, I cannot select (see) null data.

How can I see all data?

- If PRODUCT_ID **equals** CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_ID

**or**

- PRODUCT_ID **not null** CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_ID?

Any help will be appreciated greatly.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at how to do Outer Joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_STORED_PROCEDURE]
AS
BEGIN  
  SELECT 
     CUSTOMER_NAME,
     CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_ID
  FROM CUSTOMER
  Left Outer JOIN PRODUCT ON PRODUCT_ID = CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_ID
END
```

Using Left outer join returns the all the data from Customer table with the matching rows in the product table and also returns null when rows are unmatched